# Promise.all execution takes a lot of time with lot of promises

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to verify the existence of a list of files in Firebase Storage.
The number of files can be from 1 to N (N can grow to 1000s/10000s).

I have a `Promise.all` code executing all promises like this:

```
const filePaths = [// 10000 of paths here];
const checkExistence = async (path) => bucket.file(path).exists();

const fileStatuses = await Promise.all(filePaths.map(checkExistence);
```

I've noted that the longer `filePaths` is, the longer the `Promise.all` takes to resolve.

I've naively assumed it'd resolve in the longest call time, but it does not.
I thought there was something related to too much concurrent call, so I've tried batching but it does not improve the overall performance of the script.

The current wait time can be around 90/180 seconds.

Can someone explain to me why? What is the most effective (the fastest) solution to wait for thousands of asynchronous requests?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: There is likely not infinite resources. If you fire off many many calls, they'd be handled by a thread pool or something, instead of trying to DOS the server. That would likely be both on your end as well as at the server you call - servers don't tend to like being DOS-ed with thousands and thousands of calls. Finally, there might also be some throttling.  Overall, I wouldn't be surprised if multiple thousands of calls take a while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The current while varies from 90 seconds to 180 seconds, is that what we would expect?

Comment: Depends on what is sending the requests on your end and what is handling them on the other end and if there is any rate-limiting and if so what (e.g., later calls take more time). I just cannot give you concrete numbers but 90-180 seconds sounds plausible for *many* calls.